# How to set IsSelected Property on top level TreeViewItem object from WPF TreeView Control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview, treeviewitem

I work with the following `TreeView` Control and `HierarchicalDataTemplate`. The Property `DataList` in the Code Behind is initialized with a List of Typ `List<Foo>` that contains the three entries: Object `a`, `b`, `c` as shown further down.

So far so good. If I try to get the `TreeViewItem` Object that represents Object `a`, I use this way in the Code Behind without success.

```
System.Int32 indexOfObjectA = 0;
TreeViewItem treeViewItem = treeViewControl.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(indexOfObjectA) as TreeViewItem;
```

The problem is, that `treeViewItem` is always null. The main aim that I have is to get the top level `TreeViewItem` on which I can call the method `Focus()`, set the property `IsSelected` to true and last but not least call the method `BringIntoView()`. The result should be that the First `TreeViewItem` in the `TreeView` will selected.

My XAML Definition:

```
<TreeView x:Name="treeViewX" ItemsSource="{Binding DataList">
    <TreeView.Resources>
       <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Name="HierarchicalDataTemplateTreeView" DataType="{x:Type namespaceX:Foo}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
        ...
       </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

My `ItemsSource` Property is bound to the `Children` Property of the object `Foo`. Object `Foo` owns the Dictionary Object `Foo.data` which contains data to present.

```
  public class Foo {
  private Dictionary<System.Int32, Foo> data = new Dictionary<Int32, Foo>();
  private System.Int32 Key {get;set;}
  private System.Int32 FirstChildKey { get; set; }
  private System.Int32 NextSiblingKey { get; set; }

  public Foo(System.Int32 key)
  {
      this.Key = key;
  }

  public Dictionary<System.Int32, Foo> Data
  {
     get
     {
        return this.data;
     }
     set
     {
        this.data = value;
     }
  }

  public List<Foo> Children
  {
      get
      {
          List<Foo> children = new List<Foo>();
          Foo child = this.FirstChild;
          while(child != null)
          {
             children.Add(child);
             child = child.NextSibling;
          }
          return children;
       }
   }

   public Foo FirstChild
   {
       get
       {
           if(null == this.Data)
              return null;
           return this.NodeWithKey(this.FirstChildKey);
       }
   }

   public Foo NextSibling
   {
       get
       {
          if(null == this.Data)
             return null;
          return this.NodeWithKey(this.NextSiblingKey);
       }
   }

   private Foo NodeWithKey(System.Int32 key)
   {
       Foo foo;
       bool success = this.Data.TryGetValue(key, out foo);
       if(success)
         return foo;
       else
         return null;
   }
}
```

The initialization is as follow.

```
/// +---+
/// | a |
/// +---+         
/// | b | ---+    
/// +---+    |                  +---+
/// | c |    |             +--> | e |
/// +---+    |             |    +---+ 
///          |             | 
///          |    +---+    |   
///          +--> | d | ---+           
///               +---+                

Dictionary<System.Int32, Foo> data = new Dictionary<System.Int32, Foo>();
Foo a = new Foo(1);
Foo b = new Foo(2);
Foo c = new Foo(3);
Foo d = new Foo(4);
Foo e = new Foo(5);
data.Add(a.Key, a);
data.Add(b.Key, b);
data.Add(c.Key, c);
data.Add(d.Key, d);
data.Add(e.Key, e);

a.NextSiblingKey = b.Key;
b.FirstChildKey = d.Key;
b.NextSiblingKey = c.Key
d.FirstChildKey = e.Key
a.Data = data;
b.Data = data;
c.Data = data;
d.Data = data;
e.Data = data;
```

What I am doing wrong? Thanks for help.

Comment: There are a lot of errors in your code. Correct them and make sure that the code compiles before seeking solutions to other problems.

Comment: Thanks Novitchi S for your feedback. The syntax errors are now fixed.

Comment: I recommend you use MVVM.

Comment: At KCL: I use MVVM in my Application. The problem that I have to solve is, to get the top level TreeViewItem Objects on which I can call the method Focus(), set the property IsSelected to true and call the method BringIntoView(). The main aim is to select the TreeViewItem in the TreeView.

Comment: Just found this nice MSDN Article https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/36aca7f7-0b47-488b-8e16-840b86addfa3/getting-treeviewitem-for-the-selected-item-in-a-treeview?forum=wpf. Perhaps is a workaround for my problem. I will keep you up-to-date.